# Portable heat/air system

Tags: heating

Okay it is clear that the portable heat and air system has to be vented outside for the air conditioning but does it have to be vented outside for the Heat? I have an idylist portable heating and cooling system

Answer (score 1):

Electric heating elements like they use in the Idylist units do not need venting. Some units do work like a heat pump and may have some condensate that will need to be drained. The amount of condensate will depend on the humidity and the length of time the unit is running but for heat no vent is needed.